# Write a program that generates a list of 10 random integers between 10 and 100

Tags: java, random

I am having trouble with the following assignment:

Write a program that generates a list of 10 random integers between 10 and 100. Your program should print the values followed by how many values were odd and how many were even.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
public static void main(String[]args)
{
  for(int i = 0; i<10; i++){
        System.out.println("Random number: " + (int)(Math.random() * 101 + 10));
        if((int)(Math.random() * 101 + 10) %2 == 0){
          System.out.println((int)(Math.random() * 101 + 10) + " even numbers were generated");}
        else
          System.out.println((int)(Math.random() * 101 + 10) + "odd numbers were generated");
        }
   }
}
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You're using a new random value every time. You need to store the value if you want to reuse it.

Comment: Also, this will go from 10 to 110.

Comment: Calculate a number between 0 and 90, then add 10.

Comment: your program is almost correct, but you should store your random number to a variable, and you should store the number occurrence of even and odd in a variable respectively and increment them. And as others have said, you random generated is not between 10 to 100.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    System.out.println((int) (Math.random() * (90 + 1)) + 10);
}
```

This will generated and print 10 random integers between 10 and 100. As for the odd and even part, you can divide the number by 2 and check for the remainder. I'll leave the rest to you.

Answer (score 0):

This will generate 10 [random integers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28int%29) between 10 and 100, perform the count of [even and odd](http://www.frischcode.com/2013/11/even-odd-optimization.html) and finally display the counts.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Random rnd = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
  int even = 0;
  int odd = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    int randomNumber = 10 + rnd.nextInt(91);
    System.out.println("Random number " + (1 + i)
        + ": " + randomNumber);
    if (randomNumber % 2 == 0) {
      even++;
    } else {
      odd++;
    }
  }
  System.out.println(even + " even numbers "
      + "were generated");
  System.out.println(odd + " odd numbers "
      + "were generated");
}
```

Comment: Which library has the "Random rnd = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());" class in it? I tried adding java.swing.*; because I didn't know which library that symbol was from. I get an error that says the compiler cannot find the "class Random" symbol.

Comment: See links in answer - but http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28int%29